# Software to recognize TV show video?

Tags: database, video, video-editing

I have a lot of recorded videos. I know the show name, but don't have the episode name. Is there software to recognize episode name by video?

Comment: Don't know of any software like that, but if reverse image search services like Google Images or Tineye are able to recognize random frames from the video, then you could write a script that extracts a random frame and uploads it to one of those services

Comment: Are these digital recordings?  Depending on what format you used the closed captioning text **might** be embedded in the video.  Many formats don't but a few do.

Comment: Yes but no cc available

Answer (score 0):

Yes, apparently [Shazam](https://techcrunch.com/2012/09/16/shazam-for-tv/) can do this, not through video but through the video's audio.